# dplyr repeat rows but not in a successively order

Tags: r, dplyr, rows, repeat

I have a data frame like this:

```
data <- tibble(var = c("a", "b", "c"))


 var  
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 c
```

Now I want du duplicate each row three times, so I ran this code

```
data <- tibble(var = c("a", "b", "c")) %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 3))
```

The result is this:

```
 var  
  <chr>
1 a    
2 a    
3 a    
4 b    
5 b    
6 b    
7 c    
8 c    
9 c
```

But I want is this:

```
  var  
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 c    
4 a    
5 b    
6 c    
7 a    
8 b    
9 c
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any kind of help.

Cheers

Comment: replace `each` with `times` in `rep` function.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data <- tibble(var = c("a", "b", "c"))
bind_rows(rep(list(data), 3))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   var  
#>   <chr>
#> 1 a    
#> 2 b    
#> 3 c    
#> 4 a    
#> 5 b    
#> 6 c    
#> 7 a    
#> 8 b    
#> 9 c
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>